# I have problem when I want change direction of quasar to rtl

Tags: quasar

I try to change direction of quasar to RTL with quasar cli and I add it to quasar.conf.js :

```
   build: {
      rtl: true,
    },
```

but it do not work.
can I help me?

Comment: I don't know quasar, but it looks like more config is needed, than just setting that true: https://quasar.dev/options/rtl-support

Comment: @PaulT. it says when use quasar cli , just add `   build: {
      rtl: true,
    },`